# Shortcut key to focus the results pane in SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a shortcut key to focus the results pane? I know that Ctrl+R shows and hides it but the pane is not focused which means I can't scroll down using PgDn or the arrow keys. I've looked at the keyboard shortcuts but haven't found anything. Also, be able to focus back to the query editor pane.

SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I hate to post a one-liner as an answer, but:

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to toggle between the panes.

Comment: so add a link to the full keyboard shortcuts to make it more valuable... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Oh good, right next to `F5` which will execute the query. That's safe